# How do you interpret the results of an anova(model)?

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

This seems like a simple question, so apologies if it is already repeated elsewhere (though I could not find the answer when I searched for it).

I coded a linear mixed effects model as follows using R:

```
lmer(n ~ 0 + data.type + time.point + pH 
           + data.type:time.point
           + data.type:pH 
           + pH:time.point
           + (1|pond), data)
```

Here, I am looking for differences in species detection (n) using different methods (data.type) at different sampling time points (time.point) and pH conditions (pH). I then coded anova(model), and received the following output:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                      Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
data.type            152.941  50.980     3  67.694 20.1958 1.860e-09 ***
time.point           139.188  69.594     2 101.406 27.5696 2.746e-10 ***
pH                    54.969  18.323     3  12.377  7.2586  0.004612 ** 
data.type:time.point  48.001  12.000     4  96.650  4.7539  0.001521 ** 
data.type:pH          13.286   2.214     6  96.650  0.8772  0.514711    
time.point:pH         23.233   3.872     6 100.834  1.5340  0.174702    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am quite confused now on how I am to interpret the significance of this output. For example, would I say that the data type has a significant effect on species detection? I am particularly confused about how to interpret individual main effects.

Thanks in advance for any advice (or resources)!

Comment: You might be getting into trouble by omitting the intercept. In a simple situation that can simplify the interpretation of the coefficients, but I'm not sure if that works with your multiple interaction terms. It's safer to include the intercept and then use post-modeling tools like those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to compare specific scenarios. Please try repeating your model with the intercept included, as I'm afraid that answering a question on this particular model would lead you astray.

Comment: Type III ANOVA can be tricky; if you didn't change the coding of categorical predictors from the default treatment coding to sum coding or another orthogonal coding type then you might not get reliable results. Please edit the question to specify the function you used for ANOVA.